# How does Haskell actually define the + function?

Tags: haskell

While reading [Real world Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/beta/) I came up with this note:

```
ghci> :info (+)
  class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
  -- Defined in GHC.Num
  infixl 6 +
```

But how can Haskell define `+` as a non-native function? At some level you have to say that `2 + 3` will become assembler i.e. machine code.

Comment: I understand this question as 'How can I define + as a non-native function without using assembly primitives at some level?'. Another possible variant is 'How actual Haskell implementation define +?'. Please edit your question to clarify which answer(s) you want.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `+` function is overloaded and for some types, like `Int` and `Double` the definition of `+` is something like

```
instance Num Int where
    x + y = primAddInt x y
```

where `primAddInt` is a function the compiler knows about and will generate machine code for.

The details of how this looks and works depends on the Haskell implementation you're looking at.

Comment: In GHC, the corresponding function is `+# :: Int# -> Int# -> Int#`. Thus, the implementation is something like `I# a + I# b = I# (a +# b)`

Answer (score 5):

It is in fact possible to define numbers without ANY native primitives. There are many ways, but the simplest is:

```
data Peano = Z | S Peano
```

Then you can define `instance Num` for this type using pattern-matching. The second common representation of numbers is so called Church encoding using only functions (all numbers will be represented by some obscure functions, and + will 'add' two functions together to form third one).

Very interesting encodings are possible indeed. For example, you can represent arbitrary precision reals in [0,1) using sequences of bits:

```
data RealReal = RealReal Bool RealReal | RealEnd
```

In GHC of course it is defined in a machine-specific way by using either primitives or FFI.

Comment: That definition of `RealReal` is not very good if you want computable arithmetic.

Comment: Where do you see problems? As long as we don't pattern match digits they are not computed.

Comment: If you never plan to use any of the bits then you don't have to represent them at all.  :)

Comment: Assuming you are going to look at some initial segment of the bits then you run into trouble definition addition, because you cannot bound the lookahead to determine the carry.  E.g., 0.010101... + 0.0010101...  What's the first after the .?  You would have to look infinitely far to determine it.  Which means addition cannot produce even a single bit of the result.

Comment: You need more redundancy to make this work.  E.g., `data Bit = MinusOne | Zero | One; data RealReal = RealReal Bit RealReal`.

Comment: I'm never interested in all of them, and any finitely many bits of an arithmetic result can be precisely computed for any reasonably defined operands, I hope. Looks like I must ask that as a question, so I edited my post for now.

Comment: You should look into the field of exact real arithmetic.  It's pretty well studied.

Comment: The whole point of having infinite lists of digits is to have stream algorithms on the, i.e., something that can take two streams and incrementally add them.  And the more digits you ask for the more you get.  You representation doesn't work for that.  If instead you want to work with better and better finite approximations (i.e. Cauchy sequences) there is no point in having a stream of digits.  Use a stream of rationals instead.

Comment: Yeah I thought of cauchy sequences, but streams seemed to be just a particular kind of cauchy sequences if you see them as (1-digit approximation, 2-digit approximation, ...). I chose it as it required less type machinery. For sequence of rationals I need a separate type for naturals, and digit stream was simpler.

Comment: @nponeccop Streams of bits are a particular kind of Cauchy sequences, but they are unfortunately not closed under, for example, addition, as demonstrated by augustss above.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah, I've just read a book on exact real arithmetics and it says that bit streams are a bad idea.